# Golang mysql server version for the right syntax to use near ',)' at line 1

Tags: mysql, go

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',)' at line 1

```
type nameses struct {
    Name    string
    Surname string
}

var name nameses


insert, err := db.Query("INSERT INTO register(`name`,`surname`) VALUES(" + name.Name + "," + name.Surname + ")")
```

I connected database on golang very well but I could not find the syntax error. Thank you for your help now.

Comment: Looks like `name.Name` and `name.Surname` are empty strings.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing single quotes around the name and surname, because they are strings

```
insert, err := db.Query("INSERT INTO register(`name`,`surname`) VALUES('" + name.Name + "','" + name.Surname + "')")
```

But you should urgently switch to prepared statements

```
stmt, err := tx.Prepare("INSERT INTO register(`name`,`surname`) VALUES (?,?)")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer stmt.Close() // prepare statement failed and mus be checked!

_, err = stmt.Exec(name.Name,name.Surname)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
}

err = tx.Commit()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "danger!" after `stmt.Close()`?

Comment: when the prepared statemnt fails, is something very wrong and must be inbverstigated. maybe attention something went wirong, is a better term

Comment: Did you mean to put the comment after `log.Fatal()`?